# How to make composite objects global to derived classes using polymorphism?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, composition

I have written a program that allows users to take out and return vehicles. For example, a user decides to take a car out for personal use, the amount of vehicles left would then be decremented from 2 to 1. The problem is that whenever a new object is created, the amount of vehicles in the composite vehicle class would always be defaulted 2 and when you check out a vehicle, it would only decrement the amount of vehicles for that object created. I am not so good at explaining so maybe this would help.

```
int main(){
int a = 0;
int vn;
int counter = 0;
VMS *tracking[20];
while (a != 6){
    cout << "(1) Company (2) Personal (3) Carpool (4) Cargo (5) Return a vehicle (6) Exit" << endl << "Select the appropriate application: ";
    cin >> a;
    switch (a){
    case 1: tracking[counter] = new company(); cout << "YOU ARE USER #" << counter << " PLEASE REMEMBER YOUR USER NUMBER"; counter++; break;
    case 2: tracking[counter] = new personal(); cout << "YOU ARE USER #" << counter << " PLEASE REMEMBER YOUR USER NUMBER"; counter++; break;
    case 3: tracking[counter] = new carpool(); cout << "YOU ARE USER  #" << counter << " PLEASE REMEMBER YOUR USER NUMBER"; counter++; break;
    case 4: tracking[counter] = new cargo(); cout << "YOU ARE USER #" << counter << " PLEASE REMEMBER YOUR USER NUMBER"; counter++; break;
    case 5: cout << "Please enter your User #: "; cin >> vn; tracking[vn]->returned(); break;
    case 6: exit(1); break;//exit
    }
```

So every time 1 - 4 has been selected a new object will be created and every time there will be a new instance of the composite vehicle class that defaults 2 to the amount of vehicles remaining. What i am looking to do is somehow make the amount of vehicles in class vehicle decrement globally for all objects created so that when the amount of vehicles = 0, a prompt will display such. Is there any way to accomplish this by still having a vehicle class composition in the base class?
I am not so sure what code to include that will help so i think these may be helpful.
BASE CLASS:

```
class VMS{
public:
    VMS(){}
    virtual void set();
    virtual void print();
    virtual void returned();
    virtual void setV();
private:
    string purpose;
    string dName;
    int emplidNum;
    string date;
    string Time;
    string rtime;
    vehicle vehicle;//Composition of vehicle class
};
#endif
```

VEHICLE CLASS: (COMPOSITION)

```
class vehicle{
public:
vehicle() { sedan = 2, pickup = 2, minivan = 2; }
bool empty1(){
    if (sedan == 0){
        cout << "All Vehicles of this type are in use, please select a different vehicle" << endl;
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
bool empty2(){
    if (pickup == 0){
        cout << "All Vehicles of this type are in use, please select a different vehicle" << endl;
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
bool empty3(){
    if (minivan == 0){
        cout << "All Vehicles of this type are in use, please select a different vehicle" << endl;
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
//the vehicle objects
int sedan;
int pickup;
int minivan;
};
#endif
```

Sorry for the length of the post. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To make the values independent of any instance of the class you can use static variables. You simply declare the variables `static` in your class and they will be the same variable for all instances of the class. If you change your declarations of `sedan`, `pickup` and `minivan` to

```
static int sedan;
static int pickup;
static int minivan;
```

the variables will be global.

You will not be able to initialize these in the constructor of the class as doing that will reset the values each time a new instance of `vehicle` is created. You will have to have an initializer method to initialize the values. So if you create a method like this

```
static void vehicle::init()
{
    sedan = 2;
    pickup = 2;
    minivan = 2;
}
```

and you call it at the start of your program the values will be initialized as in your code.

You can read more about `static` [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static) and storage duration specifiers [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration).

---

As dwcanillas pointed out, a more oop way of accomplishing this would be to have a `garage` class that keeps track of some vehicles. So you could have a class like this

```
class garage
{
public:
   vehicle getVehicle();
   void returnVehicle();

   garage(int numVehicles);

private:
   int numVehicles;

};
```

which keeps track of all vehicles, or only keeps track of a specific subset of the vehicles, so you might have one `garage` for sedans, one for minivans and one for pickups.

Comment: This answer is correct, but there it seems like there is also a flaw in the OP's design.  It would make more sense to have a `Garage` class that acts as a distributor of `vehicles` and keeps track of how many of each `vehicle` are available.

Comment: Hi, i am very thankful for this answer but it seems when i write 
static int sedan = 2, i get an error and i must make this 
const static int sedan = 2. If it is const i will have no way of decrementing and incrementing the vehicles.

Comment: @ricefieldboy Sorry, edited to fix that. You have to have an initializer method to initialize static variables that aren't const.